# Check for exsistence of class members from a polymorphic pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Consider these classes:

```
Struct Bar1: Abstract {
  int bar;
};

Struct Bar2: Abstract {
  int bar;
};

Struct Foo1: Abstract {
  int foo;
};

Struct Foo2: Abstract {
  int foo;
};
```

You are given an `Abstract * p;` and you would like to check if you can use it to access the member `bar`. This obviously requires that `p` is pointing to one of `Bar1, Bar2` or any other `BarX` classes that you may add in future.

I know that this doesn't look very nice, but I couldn't find a way out (the full design is way to complicate to be discussed here). What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: A possibility that I have found is to exploit multiple inheritance defining `Struct BarMember { int bar };` and changing `Struct Bar1: Abstract, BarMember {};`. Then I can directly `dynamic_cast<BarMember*>(p)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a multi-level inheritance in C++ and add more and more specialization in each level. So I would solve it using the following way.

```
struct Bar : public Abstract {
    int bar;
};

struct Bar1 : public Bar {};
struct Bar2 : public Bar {};
```

Then all `BarX` objects will have a common attribute `bar`.